# How to load data from database to TreeView when parent and child in the same table

Tags: c#, mysql, treeview

I have LearningObject table in Database which contains (ID, level, subject, type).
The Level field contains (One, Two, Three). For each level there are many subjects. 
I need to load data from this database to TreeView: each level represents as a parent, and each subject represents as a child under the suitable level.
The following code bellow did not work with me to implement my idea.
I have this error
 ( An exception of type 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException' occurred in MySql.Data.dll but was not handled in user code
Additional information: Unknown column 'one' in 'where clause')

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    fill_Tree2();
}

public void fill_Tree2()
{
    DataSet PrSet = PDataset("Select DISTINCT level from learningobject");
    TreeView1.Nodes.Clear();
    foreach (DataRow dr in PrSet.Tables[0].Rows)
    {
        TreeNode tnParent = new TreeNode();
        tnParent.Text = dr["level"].ToString();
        tnParent.Value = dr["level"].ToString();
        tnParent.PopulateOnDemand = true;
        tnParent.ToolTip = "Click to get Child";
        tnParent.SelectAction = TreeNodeSelectAction.SelectExpand;
        tnParent.Expand();
        tnParent.Selected = true;
        TreeView1.Nodes.Add(tnParent);
        FillChild(tnParent, tnParent.Value);
    }
}

public void FillChild(TreeNode parent, string ParentID)
{
    DataSet ds = PDataset("Select subject,level from learningobject where level =" + ParentID.ToString());
    parent.ChildNodes.Clear();
    foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
    {
        TreeNode child = new TreeNode();
        child.Text = dr["subject"].ToString().Trim();
        child.Value = dr["level"].ToString().Trim();
        if (child.ChildNodes.Count == 0)
        {
            child.PopulateOnDemand = true;
        }
        child.ToolTip = "Click to get Child";
        child.SelectAction = TreeNodeSelectAction.SelectExpand;
        child.CollapseAll();
        parent.ChildNodes.Add(child);
    }
}

protected DataSet PDataset(string Select_Statement)
{
    string connStr = @"Data Source=localhost;Database=ahsschema;User Id=webuser;Password=";
    using (MySqlConnection SqlCon = new MySqlConnection(connStr))
    {
        MySqlDataAdapter ad = new MySqlDataAdapter(Select_Statement, SqlCon);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ad.Fill(ds);
        return ds;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this statement

```
 DataSet ds = PDataset("Select subject, level FROM learningobject WHERE level ='"+ ParentID.ToString()+"'");
```

Can't comment so had to put it here sorry if it did not help

Comment: @Kason The " ? done. You need to state which part of it. Sorry i missed it at least comment before instant down voting..... and thanks for looking through my  profile and pointing it out

Comment: Stil error, I think this is simple, you should find it and fix it by yourself. After fixed all the bug, the down vote would become up vote, dont worry about that.